# VBA Sorting Comma Separated Array - Not sorting

Tags: arrays, vba, sorting, for-loop

I'm trying to sort this array by the second number in the CSV. The result should be "1,7" first.

I have it split by comma in the for loop, so it should be comparing 0 to 7 and listing that first.

I'm not very talented with VBA. Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong here?

```
Public Function SortArray(ByRef arr() As Variant) As Variant

Dim temp As String, temparr As Variant
Dim i As Long, j As Long
Dim tempspi As String, tempspj As String

ReDim arr(5)

arr = Array("0,0", "1,7", "2,0", "3,1", "4,3", "5,1")

For i = LBound(arr) To UBound(arr) - 1
tempspi = Split(arr(i), ",")(1)
    For j = i + 1 To UBound(arr)
    tempspj = Split(arr(j), ",")(1)
        If CLng(tempspi) > CLng(tempspj) Then
            temp = arr(i)
            arr(i) = arr(j)
            arr(j) = temp
        End If
    Next j
Next i

For Each Item In arr
    Debug.Print Item
Next

SortArray = arr



End Function
```

**DEBUG RESULT:**

```
0,0
5,1
4,3
3,1
2,0
1,7
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The flagged optimization is outside of the `j` loop, so if a swap occurs it will not update to reflect the swapped-in value at index `i`

```vb
For i = LBound(arr) To UBound(arr) - 1
    tempspi = Split(arr(i), ",")(1)       '<<< not updated in the `j` loop if a swap occurs
    For j = i + 1 To UBound(arr)
        tempspj = Split(arr(j), ",")(1)
        If CLng(tempspi) > CLng(tempspj) Then
            temp = arr(i)
            arr(i) = arr(j)
            arr(j) = temp
        End If
    Next j
Next i
```

You should move that inside of the `j` loop so it always reads the current value from `arr(i)`:

```vb
For i = LBound(arr) To UBound(arr) - 1
    For j = i + 1 To UBound(arr)
        tempspi = Split(arr(i), ",")(1)       '<< move here
        tempspj = Split(arr(j), ",")(1)
        If CLng(tempspi) > CLng(tempspj) Then
            temp = arr(i)
            arr(i) = arr(j)
            arr(j) = temp
        End If
    Next j
Next i
```